# I've uninstalled/deleted bash and it's killed the server

Tags: linux, bash, opensuse, sles

I changed the default shell to zsh.  And then proceeded to uninstall bash (this was via yast on SLES).

To my horror I start to see everything deleted/uninstalled, apache, mysql .

I can't putty into the box any more.

Anyway to revive this one?

It's a VM on a server with a iDrac connection, but the web interface showing the console is blank.

So I've shut the VM (VMWare) down and copied to my desktop.

Running the VM I get the grub boot with Floppy only screen.

Is there a way in to mount and copy files?

Comment: Physical or virtual box?  Though in either case, the answer is pretty much the same, I fear: restore from backups.

Comment: Ok, it's a VM.  Thank goodness I didn't do on live box ...

Comment: Can you get a serial connection to the box? If so you may be able to revive it, but it might be more work than it's worth.

Comment: Lesson learned: don't delete bash.

Comment: Oh, it's a VM? In that case, revert to the snapshot you made before embarking on this misadventure. Easily solved.

Comment: One does not *simply* rip out a core part of your distribution, upon which many things rely

Answer (score 0):

Open the VM with VMware Player or similar and boot with SystemRescueCD iso in the "CD drive".

Within the recovery OS you can mount the drive and copy off data, via scp (may need to change VM network settings to bridged and use DHCP).